# result different in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, integration-testing

I have a problem concerning compability with safari navigator

Here is the link of the site : http://91.229.20.199/category/chevaux-a-vendre/

the problem is in the text inside the picture i want it to be like chrome

[result that i want to be in safari too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLkp9.png)

and here is the code css for this text :

```css
.title_home {
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(134,35,20,0.8);
    width: 75%;
    min-height: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 12%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

I need to add

display: -webkit-flex;